# mysql rows affected yes but table is still empty

Tags: python, mysql, rows

I've got a Python script talking to a MySQL database.

This script has been working fine for months.

All of a sudden it isn't actually adding anything to the tables it's supposed to modify.

The script has a lot of print statements and error handlers and it still runs exactly as if it was working, but nothing shows up in the database.

It even prints out "rows affected: 108" or whatever, but when I go look at the database in phpMyAdmin it says there are zero rows in the table.

The only thing it will do is truncate the tables. There's a section at the beginning that truncates the relevant tables so the script can start filling them up again. If I manually create a new row in a table through phpMyAdmin, that row will disappear when the script runs, like it's properly truncating the tables. But nothing after that does anything. It still runs without errors, but it doesn't actually modify the database.

Comment: Last time I used Python's MySQL connector, it does not commit transactions by default. You have to commit explicitly. Maybe there's a global config that controls this? Whereas TRUNCATE TABLE does an implicit commit regardless of the client. So I would guess something changed in your app config so that it doesn't commit updates anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, yeah for some reason the script was no longer autocommitting by default.

I added "cnx.autocommit(True)" and it's working again.